# grabbing username and password hashes from /etc/security/passwd

Tags: text-formatting

I have a list of usernames which i need to sync their passwords over to a new server.

How would I go about extracting the username and password hash from the /etc/security/passwd file into the below format

```
username:MGURSj.F056Dj
```

The passwd file is in stanza format

```
username:
  password = MGURSj.F056Dj
  lastupdate = 623078865
```

Comment: That file and syntax hints at an AIX system; is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the file with `awk`:

```
awk '
  /^[[:alnum:]]*:/ {
        user=substr($0, 1, index($0, ":") - 1)
        }
  /^ *password *=/ {
        split($0, elements, " *= *");
        print user ":" elements[2]
        }' \
  /etc/security/passwd
```

The idea behind the script is to first find the username line -- one starting with and containing alphanumeric characters, followed by a colon -- and extract that username with the "substr" function. On lines that start with zero or more spaces followed by the string "`password`", followed by zero or more spaces and an equals-sign, we split the line across the equals-sign and print the saved username with the password portion of the current line.